# Disable adding file in File Sharing for iTunes

Tags: ios, file, itunes, file-sharing

Is it possible to make it so you can only 'Save To...' in the iTunes File Sharing? I want the user to be able to export files from the app, but not be able to add/import to the app on the device. Does that make sense?

I have tried googling it, but can't find any articles on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to make the file sharing only one-way. If the user can save a file, a user can also add, delete, and rename files.

Keep in mind that the user can make such changes without the device even being connected. The next time the device does a sync, the files will be updated.

You could make existing files read-only. That should at least prevent deletions and renames but not additions. Of course your app can detect the additions and simply delete or ignore the new files as needed.